# EMF parsed xml file replaces double quotes with &quot; symbol

Tags: java, xml-parsing, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I am parsing xml file with EMF modelling, file gets parsed successfully but when I write parsed file to newer xml file(after some modifications) I am seeing that double quote(") symbol gets replaced with `&quot;` symbol, how to avoid it ?

original xml file content :

```
<Description>"Prepro Unrecognised preprocessor directive - ignored because it occurs in a FALSE arm of a '#if' group."</Description>
```

parsed output xml file :

```
<Description>&quot;Prepro Unrecognised preprocessor directive - ignored because it occurs in a FALSE arm of a '#if' group.&quot;</Description>
```

Java code I tried to save object :

```
                  try {
                        Resource resourceNew = new SevReportResourceFactoryImpl()
                        .createResource(URI.createFileURI("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\output2.xml"));
                        resourceNew.getContents().add(objQACCodeAnalysis);
                        Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        options.put(XMIResource.OPTION_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
                        options.put(XMIResource.OPTION_LAX_WILDCARD_PROCESSING,Boolean.TRUE);
                        resourceNew.save(options);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I think I am missing something while writing the file or may be using `XMIResource.OPTION_LAX_WILDCARD_PROCESSING` wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

The XMI file generated by EMF to persist instance models deals with the encoded quotes; why not reuse this framework to read and write models to let your own code focus on fonctionnal aspects ?